# Help with some dimensional data formulas

Tags: mysql, dimensions

I have most of my datetime dimensions defined but having trouble with these. Have 0 idea how to implement these in mysql for creating my datetime dimensions.

**Minute of day** - 1440 minutes span.
**Day per Bi-weekly** - 14 days span - from 1st week of year, starting at 1st day of year.
**Day per quarter** - 4 quarters per year, so within those quarters need day count like 1st day of quarter, 2nd day, etc.
**Week per quarter** - Same like day per quarter but at the week level.

One way i can slve these is by using CASE statements for each time interval but that is too much, like (if hour = xx & minute = xx then minuteOFDay = xxxx).  Same for the other data but I am sure there must be a 1-2 line formula to get these instead?

Comment: 4 quarters per year, yes; however, are those divided by months or by days? (the distinction becomes important in leap years)

Comment: We are dividing by month. These are for fisical quarters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "minute of day", you can use this (assuming that you have your data as `DATETIME` named `eventdt`):

```
SELECT (HOUR(`eventdt`) * 60) + MINUTE(`eventdt`)
   AS minute_of_day FROM `your_table`
```

For "day per bi-weekly", day of year modulo 14 might be usable:

```
SELECT (DAYOFYEAR(`eventdt`) % 14) AS day_per_biweekly
   FROM `your_table`
```